# Can i transfer my Xcode 5.1.1 contents in project file into Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

Can everything just simply copy and paste over from Xcode 5.1.1 to Xcode 6 for Objective-C? I don't want to re-create the entire game app from scratch on Xcode 6. If i could just copy and paste from Xcode 5.1.1 to Xcode 6 i'd do it. Or does Xcode 6 completely overwrite and delete Xcode 5.1.1 projects?

Is it possible to implement iOS 8 and 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch iPhone simulators in Xcode 5.1.1?

Comment: so you have one .xcodeproj file, Xcode is an IDE, just open the project in Xcode 6, no need to copy or do anything

Comment: Do you mean if i download Xcode 6.1.1 my universal device game app that i'm building in Xcode 5.1.1 will automatically transfer into a file for Xcode 6.1.1 as soon as i open it? Or what steps would i need to take? I'm afraid to update to Xcode 6.1.1 because i don't want to never be allowed to access my Xcode 5.1.1 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to update any projects to be compatible with Xcode 6 if they were created in Xcode 5. Simply open the project file (or the workspace if you're using that, such as with CocoaPods), and ensure that it's using the Xcode 6 program.

There are some differences between the two versions, but nothing that will cause your project to break. The main worry for that is updating to be using the iOS 8 SDK, but that usually is simply new deprecated warnings. If you have problems with that, ask a separate question with details on that.

You cannot use Xcode 5 to work in iOS 8 and the 4.7 inch/5.5 inch sims. Even if you found a way, you shouldn't - Xcode 6 will receive the new updates and patches from Apple, so you should go ahead and upgrade. It's relatively painless, I promise. (Now, anyway... it was rough when it first came out, but that time has mostly passed.)

Additionally, you'll want to re-download the 7.1 simulators, as they do a sort of half uninstall whenever you update Xcode. You can access the download button for those through Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads. Just click the button to the right of the sims (and the docs if you're interested in those). It won't be a full download, mostly just a reinstall of the programs.

Comment: So if i download Xcode 6.1.1, it says it automatically downloads ios8 as well. However, if i download 6.1.1 and i open my universal device project as usual it'll automatically open as a project in Xcode 6.1.1?

Comment: Yes, it'll automatically download the iOS 8 SDK, and it will default to the most recent version of that SDK to all future generated projects from Xcode 6 in the build settings.

If you have both Xcode 5 and 6 installed, then your mac may try to open the project in one or the other, depending on preferences and the OS version. To guarantee you're opening it in the newest version, you can right click on the project file and choose Open With and select the Xcode version you want to use.

Comment: Last question. In Xcode 5.1.1 i'm building my app for iOS 6, iOS 7. In Xcode 6.1.1, can i build for iOS 6 and iOS 7 or is it only iOS 8 for Xcode 6.1.1? Also, thank you for the time you took to answer my questions.

Comment: Yes, you can set it to iOS 6 (though I believe that's as low as it will go). Open up the General tab on the Target and set the Deployment Target in Deployment Info. It might be defaulted to a higher version, even if it's currently set correctly, when opening it in Xcode 6 for the first time, so be sure to check that.

I'm glad I've been helpful. Mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it. :)

Comment: I downloaded Xcode 6.1. Is Xcode 6.1 not compatible with AudioToolbox.framework? My sounds worked perfectly fine with that framework in Xcode 5.1.1 but no sound works in the simulators in Xcode 6.1. I use .aiff sounds. Does Xcode 6.1 use another sound framework for .aiff sounds?

Comment: That's not the problem. As I said, updating to the iOS 8 SDK can cause some hiccups but everything is perfectly solvable. Open a new question with tags specifically for iOS 8 and AudioToolbox and explain what you're trying to do, ideally with some code.